# How can we use Node.js with Html/Bootstrap to develop Mobile App

Tags: node.js, html

I want to develop Mobile App using Node.js and Html5/Bootstrap as frontend?

I searched the web , but not getting any proper source of look. I am New in Node.js , but i Know HTML5 / Bootstrap.

Can anyone Guide me through to Develop Mobile App using these two?

Answer (score 0):

While this is an opinionated question/answer and shouldn't be on SO, I'll share my experience as I was in the same boat recently:

- For the front-end (The app): Look up PhoneGap (Apache Cordova) to get an idea about building cross-platform mobile apps using HTML5/CSS/JS. Keep in mind that you can use a good amount of front-end frameworks to ease your workload (AngularJS, Framework7, jQuery, etc.)
- For the back-end (Server): Node.js is a great start, however you'll need to code your backend almost from scratch this way. I suggest looking up "Parse Server" to use it for your backend. It's an open-source solution for mobile apps backends (MBaaS). If you still decide to code your own full backend, then I highly recommend learning MEAN stack (MonogoDB, Express.js, AngularJS, Node.js), it might take you a while, but the portable experience you'll get is huge.

Either way, if you want to make high performing apps, it's always recommended to go native (Android apps using Java and Android Studio, iOS apps using XCode and Swift)

I hope this helps,

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks Marwan , Is their any Links from where i can lean Mobo App development using Node.js hardly.